# 404 Not Found when installing updates on Kali Linux

Tags: apt, upgrade, kali-linux

I get this error message after trying to do the regular updates from the notification in kali linux:

```
E: Error http://security.kali.org/ kali/updates/main libicu48 amd64 4.8.1.1-12+deb7u2
  404  Not Found
```

any help?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at http://security.kali.org/pool/main/i/icu/ you will find `libicu48_4.8.1.1-12+deb7u3_amd64.deb` but not the older `4.8.1.1-12+deb7u2`version you are trying to install.

I suspect, that the package information on your computer is outdated. Please run `apt-get update` and look out for any error messages.

If there are no errors try to upgrade again.

If there are errors, try to find out why. Are you perhaps using an older version, which doesn't get security updates anymore? Perhaps you have to adjust `sources.list`

Answer (score 1):

The single most common causes of a broken Kali Linux installation are following unofficial advice, and particularly arbitrarily populating the system’s **sources.list** file with unofficial repositories.

Open sources.list file by

`nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

Delete old content and paste this,

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
# For source package access, uncomment the following line
# deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

save, exit  and reboot

for more information, visit Kali Linux official [documentation](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories)

Comment: Well, this method will work (I guess) and anyways we are here to help each other :)

Comment: You answer needs one more thing to be complete. I've had the same problem, and your solution wouldn't work, until I've discovered that there is a blank line in /etc/apt/source.list at the beginning of the file which must be deleted. I did 3 reinstalls to make sure it has nothing to do with my activity and each came with this blank line.

Answer (score -2):

Try the following `/etc/apt/source.list`:

```
deb [arch=i386,amd64,armel,armhf] http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev main contrib non-free
deb [arch=i386,amd64,armel,armhf] http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev main/debian-installer
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev main contrib non-free

deb [arch=i386,amd64,armel,armhf] http://http.kali.org/kali kali main contrib non-free
deb [arch=i386,amd64,armel,armhf] http://http.kali.org/kali kali main/debian-installer
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali main contrib non-free

deb [arch=i386,amd64,armel,armhf] http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
```

Comment: Do not use those, use [the one recommanded on the Kali site](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories)